# difficulty with preventing D3 Hive Plot axes from intersecting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I build a D3 Hive plot for a series of data sets. For most of the data sets, the results are as expected, but for one data set, the axes are seriously misbehaving.

In particular, **the axes are not respecting the inner radius, and thus they extend inward and intersect**:

[image: Hive plot static]

I was wondering if there was some mistake in how we are defining the axes that is leading to this; here is the code for these functions:

```
  radius.domain(d3.extent(visa_lengths, function(d){ return d.length; }));



  svg.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(visa_lengths)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i){ return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(i)) + ")";})
      .attr("x1", radius.range()[0])
      .attr("x2", function(d){return radius(d.length);})
      ;
```

The full html is provided here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hive Link Plot</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .link{
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-opacity: .1;
  }


  .axis {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }



.link.active {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.node {
  stroke: #000;
}

.node.active {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/d3.hive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var source_cont = "Asia";
var target_cont = "Asia";


plot(source_cont, target_cont);

function plot(source_cont, target_cont){

var width = 1200;
var height = 1200;
var outerRadius = 500;
var innerRadius = 50;
var minLength = 5;



var visa_types = {'free': 1, 'required': 4, 'refused': 2, 'onarrival': 3, 'origin': 0};


var angle = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["origin", "free", "refused", "onarrival", "required"])
    .range([0, Math.PI/2, 11 * Math.PI / 12, 13 * Math.PI / 12, 3 * Math.PI / 2]);



var radius = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);



var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["origin", "free", "refused", "onarrival", "required"])
    .range(["yellow", "blue", "red", "orange", "green"]);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");





d3.json("reduced_pairwise_datasets.json", function(error, graph){
  nodes = graph.pairwise_nodes[source_cont + "-" + target_cont];
  links = graph.pairwise_links[source_cont + "-" + target_cont];




  // var origin_links = 

  var free_links = new Set(links.filter(function(p){ return p.target.type == 'free';}).map(function(d){return d.target.name}));
  var onarrival_links = new Set(links.filter(function(p){ return p.target.type == 'onarrival';}).map(function(d){return d.target.name}));
  var required_links = new Set(links.filter(function(p){ return p.target.type == 'required';}).map(function(d){return d.target.name}));
  var refused_links = new Set(links.filter(function(p){ return p.target.type == 'refused';}).map(function(d){return d.target.name}));



  var visa_lengths = [{'name': 'origin', 'length': 50}, {'name': 'free', 'length': free_links.size}, {'name': 'refused', 'length': refused_links.size}, {'name': 'onarrival', 'length': onarrival_links.size}, {'name': 'required', 'length': required_links.size}];


  var visa_obj = {'origin': 55, 'free': free_links.size, 'required': required_links.size, 'onarrival': onarrival_links.size, 'refused': refused_links.size}; 



  radius.domain(d3.extent(visa_lengths, function(d){ return d.length; }));



  svg.selectAll(".axis")
      .data(visa_lengths)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i){ return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(i)) + ")";})
      .attr("x1", radius.range()[0])
      .attr("x2", function(d){return radius(d.length);})
      ;




  svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", d3.hive.link()
      .angle(function(d) { return angle(visa_types[d.type]); })
      .radius(function(d) { return radius(visa_obj[d.type] * d.y); }))
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.target.type);})
      ;



  svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(visa_types[d.type])) + ")"; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return radius(visa_obj[d.type] * d.y); })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.type);})
      ;


  });
}

function degrees(radians) {
  return radians / Math.PI * 180 - 90;
}






</script>

</body>
</html>
```